# How does probability scale with length?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have a probability per length—-say a circuit segment of length 1 km has a 0.01 percent probability of igniting a fire over a period of one year. If we doubled the length to 2 km, I think we could use a binomial distribution to get the ignition probability for the new segment. How might I calculate ignition risk for non-integer multiples? A 1.25-km segment or a 0.3-km segment for instance?

Comment: Are you interested in *any* fire over a year, or the *mean* number of fires per year?

Answer (score 3):

You could assume a Poisson process, with a rate of $\lambda$ ignitions per year per kilometre, with each ignition independent of the others and uniformly distributed along the length.

So if your circuit had a length $d$ kilometres, which does not need to be an integer, the number of ignitions would follow a Poisson distribution with rate (and expectation) of $\lambda d$ per year and if $X$ is the random variable for the number in a year would have $\mathbb P(X=n)=e^{-\lambda d}\dfrac{(\lambda d)^n}{n!}$.  The probability of no ignitions would be $e^{-\lambda d}$, of one $e^{-\lambda d}\lambda d$, of two $e^{-\lambda d}\frac{(\lambda d)^2}{2}$, etc. The probability of at least one ignition would be $1-e^{-\lambda d}$.

- With $\lambda=0.0001$ (i.e. $0.01\%$) and $d=1$, this would give a probability of no ignitions of about $0.999900005$ (close to $0.9999$) and of at least one of about $0.000099995$ (close to $0.0001$), with an expected number of $0.0001$.
- With $\lambda=0.0001$ and $d=1.25$, this would give a probability of no ignitions of about $0.999875008$ (close to $0.999875$) and of at least one of about $0.000124992$ (close to $0.000125$), with an expected number of $0.000125$.
- With $\lambda=0.0001$ and $d=10000$, this would give a probability of no ignitions of about $0.36788$ and of at least one of about $0.63212$, with an expected number of ignitions $1$.

For a low rate of ignition $\lambda$ and a short distance $d$, the risk is about $\lambda \,d$, and close to linear in distance.  For large distances or high rates of ignition you also have to take into account the substantial possibility of multiple ignitions.

Comment: (+1) This homogenous point process may be good enough for the task, and is definitely worth trying as a first approximation. As a second approximation I would expect an inhomogeneous Poisson point process over time (e.g. long-term trends) and space (e.g. biogeoclimatic zones have different fire risk), which is just a matter of making $\lambda$ a non-constant function of some predictors.